# Function and Parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a game where the user should write answer (the question() function). In the question function I am using variables of 1 and 0 to get the information if the user's answer is wrong or correct. I am also using variables of 1 and 0 to see if the user has answered the questions.

```
def main():
    menu()
    anv_val = ber_val()
    val(anv_val)

def menu():
    print("1. game")
    print("2. stat")
    print("3. end")

def ber_val():
    val = input("Your choice: ")
    while val not in ["1", "2", "3"]:
        print("Print 1, 2 or 3.")
        val = input("Your choice: ")
    return val

def val(anv_val):
    if (anv_val == "1"):
        res = game()
        return res
    elif (anv_val == "2"):
        res = game()
        return stat(res)
    else:
        return end()

def question(quest, solu):
    print(quest)
    answer = input("Your answer: ")
    a_s = 1
    a_f = 0
    while (answer != solu):
        a_f = 1
        print("Try again")
        answer = input("Your answer: ")
    print("Correct!")
    a_f_s = [a_f, a_s]
    return a_f_s

def game():
    a_1 = question("Your name?", "Ricky")
    a_2 = question("Your name?", "Rong")
    a_3 = question("Your name?", "Bolly")
    sum_f = a_1[0] + a_2[0] + a_3[0]
    sum_s = a_1[1] + a_2[1] + a_3[1]
    sum_all = [sum_f, sum_s]
    return sum_all, main()

def stat(res):
    print("Questions you answered: " + str(res[1]))
    print("Wrong times: " + str(res[0]))
    return main()

main()
```

Now to my problem. In the function game(), I want to return the variable called a_f_s, AND USE the information (the information is number of error and answered questions) in my function stat(). But the problem is that in the function val(anv_val) - if the user prints "2", the function game() will run, but I want the stat() to run. I am a little bit confused.

I appreciate all the help!

Comment: so your problem is because `game()` returns `main()` so what happens is as you go through function `val()` you come to the line `res = game()` where you return `sum_all` but then call `main()` again and so on. You are stuck in a loop. You never get to the line `return stat(res)` to perform `stat()`. Since you already `return main()`in `stat()` and stat is always called after `res = game()` you can omit `return main()` from `game()`

Comment: Yes but I just want to take the returned value in question(quest, solu), the variable a_f_s and use it in stat() because there I have the information about how many times the player have answered the questions, for instance

Comment: try `return sum_all` instead of `return sum_all, main()` in `game()`. Because you are never reaching `stat()`. So you are not calling it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a global variable `end_game`, to control a while loop in `main()`. This way, you won't need to keep calling `game()`, thus simplifying your program logic. Notice that `game()` does not return a call to `main()` now.

I also made `res` a global variable that is only modified when `game()` is called. In `stat()`, the global `res` is used to print stats if it is not `None`.

```
end_game = False
res = None

def main():
    while not end_game:
        menu()
        anv_val = ber_val()
        val(anv_val)

def menu():
    print("1. game")
    print("2. stat")
    print("3. end")

def ber_val():
    val = input("Your choice: ")
    while val not in ["1", "2", "3"]:
        print("Print 1, 2 or 3.")
        val = input("Your choice: ")
    return val

def val(anv_val):
    global end_game, res
    if (anv_val == "1"):
        res = game()
    elif (anv_val == "2"):
        stat()
    else:
        end_game = True


def question(quest, solu):
    print(quest)
    answer = input("Your answer: ")
    a_s = 1
    a_f = 0
    while (answer != solu):
        a_f = 1
        print("Try again")
        answer = input("Your answer: ")
    print("Correct!")
    a_f_s = [a_f, a_s]
    return a_f_s

def game():
    a_1 = question("Your name?", "Ricky")
    a_2 = question("Your name?", "Rong")
    a_3 = question("Your name?", "Bolly")
    sum_f = a_1[0] + a_2[0] + a_3[0]
    sum_s = a_1[1] + a_2[1] + a_3[1]
    sum_all = [sum_f, sum_s]
    return sum_all

def stat():
    if res is not None:
        print("Questions you answered: " + str(res[1]))
        print("Wrong times: " + str(res[0]))
    return

main()
```

As a bonus, here is a simpler way I would write your code:

```
def main():
    res = None

    while True:
        print_menu()
        choice = get_choice()

        if (choice == "1"):
            res = game()
        elif (choice == "2"):
            stat()
        else:
            return

def print_menu():
    print("1. game")
    print("2. stat")
    print("3. end")

def get_choice():
    val = input("Your choice: ")
    while val not in ["1", "2", "3"]:
        print("Print 1, 2 or 3.")
        val = input("Your choice: ")
    return val

def question(quest, solu):
    print(quest)
    answer = input("Your answer: ")
    a_s = 1
    a_f = 0
    while (answer != solu):
        a_f = 1
        print("Try again")
        answer = input("Your answer: ")
    print("Correct!")
    a_f_s = [a_f, a_s]
    return a_f_s

def game():
    a_1 = question("Your name?", "Ricky")
    a_2 = question("Your name?", "Rong")
    a_3 = question("Your name?", "Bolly")
    sum_f = a_1[0] + a_2[0] + a_3[0]
    sum_s = a_1[1] + a_2[1] + a_3[1]
    sum_all = [sum_f, sum_s]
    return sum_all

def stat():
    if res is not None:
        print("Questions you answered: " + str(res[1]))
        print("Wrong times: " + str(res[0]))
    return

main()
```

Comment: I get it! But when I run it - when the player has played the game, I want the program to go back to menu, and when you click on stat - then the statistic should pop up. With this code everything pop up directly

Comment: @Gringo then don't call `res = game()` in `val()`. Instead make a `res` variable in `main()` or `val()` outside the conditions which you assign if `1` is called and then pass to `stat()` when `2` is called. Here everything pops up directly not because of the answer but because of your code design.

Comment: @HadiFarah is right. I've edited the code since your request is simple. As always, keep your program logically simple and you should be able to track what you need to do

Comment: I've tried in that way too but it says: "local variable 'res' referenced before assignment"

Comment: This is what I have looked for in like 1 week now. I appreciate your help. Thank u very much. (Now i need to read your code in like 1 day to understand it, i'm new to global variables)

Comment: In the stat() function, I added an else-statement where i typed that the user had answered 0 questions and that the number of errors is 0 because res = none in the statement. Is that correct? Do I think in a right way?

Comment: @Gringo yes, also you can just test it out to find out. Also, in my second code block, I removed globals so you don't have to mess around with that.

Comment: And you are welcome. You may click the check mark next to the answer to mark this question as resolved if this helped

Answer (score 1):

Two observations :

1. `Questions you answered:` will always print the same result for all as the program does not proceed until the user has answered all questions.
2. You should use `a_f = a_f + 1` to increment the count of false answers.

Comment: I know, but that is not my point. I want the to use the a_f_s in the stat() function without running the game() function